# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android' error

Tags: flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

i found the gradle version this project uses

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` the version does not exist.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3' <-- does not exist.
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

If we check the following [link](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-7-2-0-release-notes) we can see the highest version for your `gradle-wrapper.properties` should be `7.2.2`.

So change your `build.gradle` to the following:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2' <-- change this.
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```